# fabric8 springboot full example

Tags: docker, spring-boot, spring-boot-docker-plugin

I am trying to figure out how to build a spring boot docker image using fabric8 docker-maven-plugin. The documentation contains bit and bytes and I'm obviously missing something. Does anyone have a full pom.xml example for it?

Answer (score 11):

The fabric8-maven-plugin documentation is pretty hard to dig through if you just want to get started quickly, so here's a quick example for everything you need to get a Docker image built.

First, make sure `docker` is on your path and the Docker daemon is running. Run `docker ps` and ensure a response like this:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

Add this to your pom.xml and run this with `mvn clean package docker:build`

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
            <artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <images>
                    <image>
                        <!-- Replace your-project-name -->
                        <name>your-project-name:${project.version}</name>

                        <build>

                            <!-- This is the same FROM used in a Dockerfile -->
                            <from>vixns/java8</from>

                            <!-- This is the same ENTRYPOINT used in a Dockerfile -->
                            <entryPoint>
                                <exec>
                                    <arg>java</arg>
                                    <!-- This extra argument is so Tomcat can start faster due to lack of entropy -->
                                    <arg>-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom</arg>
                                    <arg>-jar</arg>
                                    <!-- /maven/ is the default dir that the plugin copies your artifact to -->
                                    <arg>/maven/${project.artifactId}.${project.packaging}</arg>
                                </exec>
                            </entryPoint>

                            <assembly>
                                <!-- This is a predefined assembly.xml that will only copy your final artifact to the Docker image -->
                                <descriptorRef>artifact</descriptorRef>
                            </assembly>
                        </build>
                    </image>
                </images>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Note: you'll need additional setup if you want to use the `mvn docker:start` command. You don't have to use it, you can use the standard `docker` command if you'd like.

Comment: works great for me, but adding project.version to arg tag.
<arg>/maven/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.${project.packaging}</arg>. Useful when no buid.finalname is set.  Thanks dustin!

Comment: That final artifect is too fat, any ideas to layer the external depencies?

Answer (score 2):

[Here is one of](http://littlebigextra.com/build-deploy-docker-image-maven/) Working example using fabric8. This project uses  spring boot docker image and then link it to mongodb.

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.20.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <!--<dockerHost>tcp://REMOTE_IP:2375</dockerHost> -->
                <images>
                    <image>
                        <name>springboot-mongo-dockerimage:${project.version}</name>
                        <alias>springboot-mongo-dockerimage</alias>
                        <build>
                            <dockerFileDir>${project.basedir}</dockerFileDir>

                        </build>
                        <run>
                            <namingStrategy>alias</namingStrategy>
                            <dependsOn>
                                <container>mongo</container>
                            </dependsOn>

                            <links>
                                <link>mongo</link>
                            </links>
                            <ports>
                                <port>8080:8080</port>
                            </ports>
                        </run>
                    </image>
                </images>
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                        <goal>build</goal>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

You can [follow this link](http://littlebigextra.com/build-deploy-docker-image-maven/) for step by step instructions

However rather than building Image from fabric8 maven plugin, you can use the Dockerfile which I find more convenient using and that is why you would notice

```
<build>
   <dockerFileDir>${project.basedir}</dockerFileDir>
</build>
```

DockerFile

```
    FROM java:8
VOLUME /tmp
ADD target/Boot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://mongo/test", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

If you want to push your images to Docker hub registry then you can use [this link](http://littlebigextra.com/push-docker-images-docker-hub-using-maven/).

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have to use that plugin, I recommend spotify's `docker-maven-plugin`. after you setup, you can do `mvn clean package docker:build` to build the docker image.

your `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
...
<properties>
   <docker.image.prefix>springio</docker.image.prefix>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.11</version>
            <configuration>
                <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                <dockerDirectory>src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                <buildArgs>
                    <finalName>${project.build.finalName}.jar</finalName>
                </buildArgs>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
```

Your `Dockerfile` in `src/main/docker` looks something like this:

```
FROM openjdk:8u102-jre
ARG finalName
ADD $finalName /my-app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/my-app.jar"]
```

References:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker

https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin

Comment: `com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin` does not support aws authentification at the moment (30 of may 2018). Yes they have an issue in github, but still it is not supported. So if you want to publish into aws repository `spotify` is not for you right now.

Comment: The question doesn't mention anything about AWS though. You can still use CI/CD to achieve that. We are using this plugin with Jenkins and are able to publish our images to Amazon Elastic Container Registry (ECR).

Comment: question is about fabric8 docker-maven-plugin not com.spotify.docker-maven-plugin

Comment: true, but the upvotes mean it helped some people as an alternative answer. better and more relevant answers are meant to pass this one as they get more upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/cvienot/spring-boot-docker-fabric8-plugin-demo) is an example of an inline assembly configuration

Add this lines to your pom file, and use mvn docker:build

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.20.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <images>
            <image>
                <name>demo/helloworld</name>
                <build>
                    <from>openjdk</from>
                    <tags>
                        <tag>latest</tag>
                        <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                    </tags>
                    <assembly>
                        <descriptorRef>artifact</descriptorRef>
                    </assembly>
                    <cmd>java -jar maven/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</cmd>
                </build>
            </image>
        </images>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dockerfile: 
... 
ADD target/<file-name>.jar <dest-dir> 
...
```

Location of Dockerfile: src/main/docker
Maven io.fabric8 docker plugin configuration

```
<configuration>
    <images>
        <image>
            <name>${docker.image.prefix}/${docker.image.name}</name>
            <alias>${project.artifactId}</alias>
            <build>
                <contextDir>${project.basedir}</contextDir>
                <tags>
                    <tag>latest</tag>
                </tags>
            </build>
        </image>
    </images>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <targetPath>${project.basedir}</targetPath>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
            <include>${project.build.finalName}.war</include>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</configuration>
```